# LWJGL Projection Matrix - Everything Disappears

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, projection-matrix

I recently began working on a project in Java using OpenGL, while not my first time I attempted to write the code in my own style rather than following tutorials directly.  I ran into a problem when attempting to apply a projection matrix.  I was able to create and display triangles, I even got as far as to use a transformation matrix (which worked fine).  Here is my code:
My main class with most of my model information.

```
public class Main{
public static Screen screen;
public static Loader loader = new Loader();
public static void main(String[] args){
    screen = new Screen();
    ModelData data = OBJFileLoader.loadOBJ("firstTest");
    BasicShader shader = new BasicShader();
    float f = 0.5f;
    RawModel rawModel = loader.loadToVAO(new float[] {
    -f, f, 0, -f, -f, 0, f, -f, 0, f, f, 0
    }, data.getTextureCoords(), data.getNormals(), new int[] {
    0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2
    });
    // RawModel rawModel1 = loader.loadToVAO(data.getVertices(),
    // data.getTextureCoords(), data.getNormals(), data.getIndices());
    ModelTexture texture = new ModelTexture(loader.loadTexture("firstTest"));
    TexturedModel model = new TexturedModel(rawModel, texture);
    Entity entity = new Entity(model, new Vector3f(0, 0, 0), 0, 0, 0, 1);
    shader.start();
    shader.loadProjectionMatrix();
    shader.stop();
    //GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);
    //GL11.glCullFace(GL11.GL_BACK);
    while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glClearColor(0.5f, 0, 1, 1);
        shader.start();
        shader.loadTransformation(Maths.createTransformationMatrix(entity.position, entity.rx, entity.ry, entity.rz, entity.scale));
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getRawModel().getVaoID());
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, model.getRawModel().getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
        shader.stop();
        screen.updateDisplay();
    }
    shader.cleanUp();
    loader.cleanUp();
    Display.destroy();
}
```

My vertex shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 position;

out vec3 color;
out vec2 gridPosition;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;

void main(void){
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * transformationMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
color = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}
```

My screen and creation of the projection matrix:

```
public class Screen{
public static final float FOV = 70, NEAR_PLANE = 0.1f, FAR_PLANE = 1000;
private static final int WIDTH = 1000, HEIGHT = 600, FPS_CAP = 120;
public static Matrix4f projectionMatrix;
public Screen(){
    createProjectionMatrix();
    ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3, 2).withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true);
    try{
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);
        Display.setTitle("Screen Test");
    }catch (LWJGLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}
public void updateDisplay(){
    Display.sync(FPS_CAP);
    Display.update();
}
private void createProjectionMatrix(){
    float aspectRatio = (float) Display.getWidth() / (float) Display.getHeight();
    float y_scale = (float) ((1f / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(FOV / 2f))) * aspectRatio);
    float x_scale = y_scale / aspectRatio;
    float frustum_length = FAR_PLANE - NEAR_PLANE;
    projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    projectionMatrix.m00 = x_scale;
    projectionMatrix.m11 = y_scale;
    projectionMatrix.m22 = -((FAR_PLANE + NEAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);
    projectionMatrix.m23 = -1;
    projectionMatrix.m32 = -((2 * NEAR_PLANE * FAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);
    projectionMatrix.m33 = 0;
}
```

I have confirmed that the matrix uniform is loaded up, that the gl_Position z is between -1 and 1 and that backface culling has done nothing.  I'm sure I've overlooked something simple but I have been at this for a day or two and decided to look for some help, if any other source is necessary I will post it.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Have a look at what I tried here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995739/render-perspective-projection-matrix-in-lwjgl-3